# how can i retrieve deleted rows in sql server 2014 management studio?

Tags: c#, sql-server

i use this code :

```
with FillingDatabase as 
(
    select *, row_number() over (partition by itid order by itid ) as rownumber 
    from item 
)

 delete from item where rownumber >1
```

the whole data in my table had gone .

im a newbie using this sql server , hope you can help me . thank you

Comment: you cannot, unless you have a backup. So please consider securing a backup as a best practice

Comment: Can you provide more information ? Do you want to trigger an action when deleting items or be able to get deleted items ?

Comment: able to get deleted items

Comment: @mhitz I hope this is not production data (kewl)

Answer (score 0):

delete from item where rownumber >1
output deleted.*

Comment: delete from table_name where condition output deleted.*

Comment: i tried it but it doesn't work , it give me this output "Incorrect syntax near 'output'."

Comment: Please share the syntax you executed.

Comment: with FillingDatabase as 
(
    select *, row_number() over (partition by itid order by itid ) as rownumber 
    from item 
)

 delete from item where itid >1

Comment: with FillingDatabase as 
(
    select *, row_number() over (partition by itid order by itid ) as rownumber 
    from item 
)

 delete from item where itid >1
 i've tried this ,  and also this :  delete from item where itid >1

Comment: don't use CTE, directly delete from item where column condition output deleted.*

Answer (score 0):

If you want to retrieve deleted rows immediately after DELETE statement use following syntax:

```
delete from item
output deleted.*
where itid > (select min(itid) from item)
```

I don't know exactly what you want to do, so I've just write simple "where" with sub-query instead of CTE. Hope this suite your needs.

Comment: i just want to get the data that i accidentally deleted using the statement above , and i already try the statement you suggested but the output is only the columns without its rows . thank you ,

Comment: If you accidentally deleted data and don't have backups, you can **try** to use [some log recovery tool](https://www.google.ru/webhp?ie=UTF-8#q=sql%20server%20log%20recovery%20tools), but, unfortunately, such tools is not silver bullet and not always can restore your data.